# Can a Clash of Clans shield Activate on its own?

Tags: clash-of-clans

One day I was just playing Clash of Clans, and I was raiding someone. Then on my screen it said that a shield was activated. After the battle I went back to my village and I saw I had a
shield activated. I didn't even go to the store and look at the shields section. (It is not the
3 day noob shield.) I was really confused. (I have a level four town hall.) Can someone help me?

Comment: It's a 12 hour shield I think.

Comment: Were you playing the game when you saw the notification?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you get a shield if you get raided. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definite answer is no. Shields can only be acquired in specific ways. According to [The Clash of Clans wiki of Shields](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Shields), these are the ways you can get shields:

### Beginning the game.

When you first begin playing Clash of Clans, you are given a 3-day shield. Once the shield expires, you will have to manually purchase shields.

### Be a victim of a successful raid.

If your village is attacked by another user, you will gain one of the following:

- *If your village is raided with 0-29% destruction and the player dropped at least 1/3 of his/her total current troop space, you will receive a village guard [depending on your current league](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Village_Guard)*
- *If your village is raided with 30-59% destruction, you will receive a 12-hour shield plus the equivalent village guard time (i.e. If you are in Gold League for example, your total "shielded time" is 12 hours and 30 minutes, **with 12 shield hours and right after your shield expires, 30 minutes village guard time.**)*
- *If your village is raided with 60-89% destruction, you will receive a 14-hour shield plus the equivalent village guard time*
- *If your village is raided with a 90% or more destruction, you will receive a 16-hour shield plus the equivalent village guard time*

### Purchase shields through the store.

Shields can be purchased through the store with [Gems](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Gems).

**A 1-day shield costs *100* gems, and takes 5 days to cool down**.

**A 2-day shield costs *150* gems, and takes 10 days to cool down**.

**A week-long shield costs *250* gems, and takes 35 days to cool down**.

So, the most probable answer is that your village was unsuccessfully raided but with a destruction amount above 29%. And in conclusion, shields cannot be activated automatically unless an event such as the ones mentioned above take place.